# How to keep one SignalRHub Context throughout the Application

Tags: dependency-injection, signalr, signalr-hub

I have an .NET core application where I have a Signal R Hub in a reference project.

```cs
  public class RecordingHub : Hub<SignalRClient>
    {
        private readonly ISignalRController _SignalRController;

        public RecordingHub(ISignalRController signalRController){
            _SignalRController = signalRController;
        }

        override public Task OnConnectedAsync(){
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception ex)
        {
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(ex);
        }
}
```

I am starting the SignalR server like this in Initialization Bootstrapper.

```cs
 public Task SetupAsync(IServiceResolutionContainer serviceResolutionContainer, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var signalRService = serviceResolutionContainer.GetInstance<ISignalRServer>();
            signalRService.Start();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

where the SignalRService is

```cs
 public Task Start()
    {
        _Host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddSingleton(_SignalRController);
                });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<SignalRConfiguration>();
                webBuilder.UseUrls("https://url:port");
            })
            .Build();


        return _Host.RunAsync();
    }
```

The code for SignalR Configuration is

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddSignalR()
            .AddJsonProtocol();
    }
    public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment _)
    {
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization(); // This needs to be between app.UseRouting(); and app.UseEndpoints();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<RecordingHub>("/api");
        });
    }
```

I start this as a reference project in an other application. In the other application, in my Program.cs I add  `services.AddSignalR()`; which adds the `IHubContext` throughout the application. But the issue is, this context is unaware of SignalR server running in the reference project.

if I remove `services.AddSignalR()`, it throws me error that `IHubContext` is not injected. Is there a way I can add just one SignalR Hub context in my reference project?

I tried with Simple Injector https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/631. This worked but by any chance is there another way to keep minimal changes in the running project and do all changes in the reference project.

Apologies if I made any mistake in explaining. Looking forward for help. Thank you